# Error in handling FCM notification when app in foreground: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am working on a flutter application where I am handling FCM notifications as follows-

```
late SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
bool isLoggedIn = false;
Future<void> _initializePrefs() async {
  log("Loading Shared Preferences");
  _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  log('Shared Preferences loaded');
  isLoggedIn = _sharedPreferences.getBool(IS_LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  showFlutterNotification(message);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

/// Create a [AndroidNotificationChannel] for heads up notifications
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    // 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
  ///
  /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
  /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_configureForegroundMessaging() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    log('new notificaiton: ${message.data}');
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android!;

//     // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
//     // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      log('Notification hascode: ${notification.hashCode} and notification title: ${notification.title} and notification body: ${notification.body}');
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              // channel.description,
              icon: 'launch_background',
              // other properties...
            ),
          ));
    }
  });
}

/// Initialize the [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin] package.
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await setupFlutterNotifications();
  }
  _configureForegroundMessaging();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  await _initializePrefs();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

When the app is in background or killed, the notification appears properly. But, when the app is in foreground I get this error-

```
E/flutter (26732): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (26732):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:425)
E/flutter (26732):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:326)
E/flutter (26732):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1146)
E/flutter (26732):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1462)
E/flutter (26732):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1299)
E/flutter (26732):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (26732):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
```

What I identified with debugging is that the code-

```
 flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              // channel.description,
              icon: 'launch_background',
              // other properties...
            ),
          ));
    }
```

in the `_configureForegroundMessaging()` method is raising the **NullPointerException.** But, I can't figure out what is the reason for that error.
**Android Manifest-**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blog_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:label="blog_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I referred- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_messages, https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example for the configuration.
Please help me reslove this problem!

Comment: The crash is caused due to `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon` & not `FCM`. Are you properly initialising the notifications plugin & setting the correct icon for notification?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using are trying to use the `flutterLocalNotificationPlugin` while it's declared as `let` try this

```
...
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

And the configuration is not supposed to be in the main
please create an initState an add it inside

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureForegroundMessaging();
..};
```